# UI exposed on button click despite request call

Tags: ios, objective-c, pushviewcontroller, ui-thread

I am working on `Objective-C` I need to hold on for request to response back and then I have to move to next screen but as soon as I hit the button UI exposed to new Screen despite the request call which takes some time.

I want to hold on to the request until it completes but unable to do so, I also tried to put my `pushViewController` code to request's response body so I can push my view after response but unable to do so.

I have tried putting `pushViewController` to response code

I have one method which I call on button click and inside the method there is request call.

Comment: Do you have any code examples for us to see what you have done so far?

Comment: Can you share some code in your question? that will be helpful ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write your function Call in between.

```
dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
// Do your Call here.
   [self YourRequest:@"YourParameters"
           completion:^{
                     // Do your Push View Controller or other stuff Here
           }];
}
```